# Need to know backend location(table name) of Customer Ship To Number in Oracle EBS

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apps, oracle-ebs

I am working in Oracle E-Business Suite. 
Considering this field "CUSTOMER_SHIP_TO_NUMBER"
[Oracle EBS Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivEvN.jpg)

I need to know the column and the table in the back-end database, from which the values of this field is getting populated. 
I tried examining the Record History, and the data is being fetched from a View, namely the OE_Order_Lines_V. I tried searching through that view but couldn't figure it out. I need to know the actual location, namely the Table, where this data (CUSTOMER_SHIP_TO_NUMBER) is being stored.

Comment: This question requires expertise in the Oracle EBS product which you are unlikely to find on a general programming site. My advice is to ask your question on [the Oracle Technet EBS forum](https://community.oracle.com/community/oracle-applications/e-business_suite/e-business-suite-technology/general_ebs_discussion)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an Oracle product not programming

Comment: @APC, just curious, does SO not cater to Oracle EBS as well? the tag `oracle-ebs` is included in the tag selection when asking a question.

Comment: @MigsIsip - Philosophically I think there is a difference between programming questions (say, performing validation on flexfield columns) and purely product related columns: what table column underlies a projection column in an Oracle-supplied view. More practically, there aren't many EBS specialists to answer questions here, compared to OTN

Comment: "More practically, there aren't many EBS specialists to answer questions here, compared to OTN" --> point taken, my EBS Questions are usually left unanswered here. @APC

Comment: If I spot Apps questions I usually direct the seeker to the OTN Forums.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query to find the customer details.

```
SELECT hp.party_name "CUSTOMER_NAME", 
hca.account_number "CUSTOMER_NUMBER",
csu.location "SHIP_TO_ORG_ID",hca.cust_account_id "CUSTOMER_ID"
FROM hz_parties hp, hz_cust_accounts hca, 
hz_cust_acct_sites_all cas, hz_cust_site_uses_all csu
WHERE hp.party_id = hca.party_id
AND hca.party_site_id = cas.party_site_id 
AND cas.cust_acct_site_id = csu.cust_acct_site_id
AND cas.address_type = 'SHIP_TO'
AND csu.location = <ship_to_org_id>;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Data comes from the Table `ONT.OE_ORDER_LINES_ALL`, under the column of `END_CUSTOMER_ID`.
This should be joined with `AR.RA_CUSTOMERS` using the column `CUSTOMER_ID` to get the Customer Name and Number:

```
SELECT  racust.customer_id
    ,   racust.customer_name
    ,   racust.customer_number  -- this is the SHIP_TO_CUSTOMER_NUMBER
FROM    AR.RA_CUSTOMERS racust
    ,   ONT.OE_ORDER_headers_all oola
where   oola.END_CUSTOMER_ID = racust.CUSTOMER_ID;
```

Read More Here: [Oracle Order Management Technical Reference Manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A89549_02/acrobat/onttrm.pdf)

Comment: I checked both the Header and the Lines table and both have the columns END_CUSTOMER_ID but strangely, none of them has any data whatsoever. While the front-end clearly has those field values. I also checked, and this value is the last 8 characters of the HZ_CUST_SITE_USES_ALL.LOCATION column.

Comment: Also, not all customers have their CUSTOMER_SHIP_TO_NUMBER same as their CUSTOMER_NUMBER.